# Tinymce 4 Elfinder absolute path to image

Tags: tinymce-4, absolute-path, elfinder

I've integrated elfinder v2.1 with TinyMce4. 
It works great except that the path to the image elfinder give to tinymce is not correct.

The simpliest solution would be to use absolute path. I found some resources to do that with previous version of tinymce (elfinder + tinymce3) but not with version 4.
I try to change some variables in connector.php but without any success.
Here is the actual code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(0); // Set E_ALL for debuging

include_once dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'elFinderConnector.class.php';
include_once dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'elFinder.class.php';
include_once dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'elFinderVolumeDriver.class.php';
include_once dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'elFinderVolumeLocalFileSystem.class.php';
// Required for MySQL storage connector
// include_once dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'elFinderVolumeMySQL.class.php';
// Required for FTP connector support
// include_once dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'elFinderVolumeFTP.class.php';


/**
 * Simple function to demonstrate how to control file access using "accessControl" callback.
 * This method will disable accessing files/folders starting from  '.' (dot)
 *
 * @param  string  $attr  attribute name (read|write|locked|hidden)
 * @param  string  $path  file path relative to volume root directory started with directory separator
 * @return bool|null
 **/
function access($attr, $path, $data, $volume) {
    return strpos(basename($path), '.') === 0       // if file/folder begins with '.' (dot)
        ? !($attr == 'read' || $attr == 'write')    // set read+write to false, other (locked+hidden) set to true
        :  null;                                    // else elFinder decide it itself
}

$opts = array(
    // 'debug' => true,
    'roots' => array(
        array(
            'driver'        => 'LocalFileSystem',   // driver for accessing file system (REQUIRED)
            'path'          => '../files/',         // path to files (REQUIRED)
            'URL'           => dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/../files/', // URL to files (REQUIRED)
            'accessControl' => 'access'             // disable and hide dot starting files (OPTIONAL)
        )
    )
);

// run elFinder
$connector = new elFinderConnector(new elFinder($opts));
$connector->run();
?>
```

Anyone knows how to retrieve an absolute url from elfinder?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by modifying connector.php file and adding the alias option

see: https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Connector-configuration-options

So, in function access, go to $opt
and modify URL and alias like this:

```
$opts = array(
    // 'debug' => true,
    'roots' => array(
        array(
            'driver'        => 'LocalFileSystem',   // driver for accessing file system (REQUIRED)
            'path'          => '../files/',         // path to files (REQUIRED)
            'URL'           => 'absolutepath/to/elfinder/files/', // URL to files (REQUIRED)
            'alias'         => 'absolutepath/to/elfinder/files/',
            'accessControl' => 'access'             // disable and hide dot starting files (OPTIONAL)
        )
    )
);
```

Hope it can help.